# Unhandled Event Loop Exception in Eclipse while using Perforce plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, p4eclipse

I am using EclipseVersion: 2022-12 (4.26.0) Build id: 20221201-1913, and I installed the Perforce Plugin P4Eclipse 2022.1 (4.25). However, whenever I am trying this right click on the project--> Team--> Share project-->Perforce --> click the "Create" button so that I can configure my perforce server, I am seeing "Unhandled Event Loop Exception" error message in the Error Log. Any idea how can I resolve this?

Comment: Go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and report that to the Perforce Plugin P4Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also waiting for the plugin to support newer Eclipse versions. As a workaround you can also install Eclipse 4.25 first, then create the Perforce connection and then update Eclipse to 4.26 (or 4.27).

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying the same with eclipse 4.27 and perforce create connection is not working, if I go to the connection wizard following Alternate menu choice: File > New > Other > Perforce > Connection
then it does not save the server and credential details, however in the backed its making the login attempt which is successful (visible on p4 console log).
Looks like compatibility issue with latest eclipse and older perforce plugin.

As I am working in offline environment, would settle for 4.25 eclipse, not sure if I can upgrade it to latest eclipse in offline mode.

Will watch for Helix to release supported plugin.